# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to (...) must be an instance of (...) integer given

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, orm, fixtures

I'm making fixtures and when I try to load them I have an error. I need an instance of a Movie object but what I give, and I don't know why, is an integer. For this reason it says me that I have the following error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
 Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document\A
 ward::setMovie() must be an instance of Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document\Movie
 , integer given, called in C:\Programming\xampp\htdocs\filmboot.web\src\Fil
 mboot\MovieBundle\DataFixtures\MongoDB\Awards.php on line 143 and defined i
 n C:\Programming\xampp\htdocs\filmboot.web\src\Filmboot\MovieBundle\Documen
 t\Award.php line 107
```

This is my Fixture class:

```
namespace Filmboot\MovieBundle\DataFixtures\MongoDB;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document\Award;

class Awards extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface {
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $awards = array(
            array(
                "name"     => "Sitges",
                "year"     => "1992",
                "category" => "Best director"
        );

        foreach ($awards as $award) {
            $document = new Award();
            $document->setName    ($award["name"]);
            $document->setYear    ($award["year"]);
            $document->setCategory($award["category"]);

            $manager->persist($document);
            $this->addReference("award-" .$i, $award);

        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
    public function getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And this is the document class:

```
namespace Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Filmboot\MovieBundle\Util;

/**
 * @ODM\Document(db="filmbootdb", collection="awards")
 * @ODM\Document(repositoryClass="Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document\AwardRepository")
 */
class Award {
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\String
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ODM\Int
     */
    private $year;

    /**
     * @ODM\String
     */
    private $category;


    /**
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Movie", mappedBy="awards", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $movie;



    public function getId()        {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        return $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()      {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setYear($year) {
        return $this->year = $year;
    }

    public function getYear()      {
        return $this->year;
    }

    public function setCategory($category) {
        return $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory()  {
        return $this->category;
    }    

    public function setMovie(\Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document\Movie $movie)   {
        $movie->setAward($this);
        return $this->movie = $movie;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As we can see you explicitly give an integer for the movie :

```
$awards = array(
            array(
                // ...
                "movie"    => 1,
            ),
          );

// ...

$document->setMovie   ($award["movie"]);
```

Instead of a movie object, so the script crashes because it requires a Movie object :

```
public function setMovie(\Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document\Movie $movie)   {
    return $this->movie = $movie;
}
```

So the solution is to create the fixtures of the movies and give them a [reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures):

```
// When saving inside Movie fixtures
$manager->persist($movie);
$manager->flush();
$this->addReference('movie-'.$i, $movie); // Give the references as movie-1, movie-2...
```

Then load them first with getOrder() method :

```
public function getOrder()
{
    return 0; // 0, loaded first
}
```

Control that Awards are loaded after movies :

```
public function getOrder()
{
    return 1; // loaded after 0...
}
```

and after in your Award fixtures retrieve them like that by reference, it will load the entire object, not just an id (integer) :

```
$awards = array(
            array(
                // ...
                "movie"    => $this->getReference('movie-1'), // Get the Movie object, not just id
            ),
          );

// ...

$document->setMovie   ($award["movie"]);
```

Please note that if you want to use reference and order, your fixture classes need to implement OrderedFixtureInterface :

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Group;

class LoadGroupData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
```

You have to do this with all your other entities like actors, directors...

You can find the documentation for sharing objects (by reference) between your fixtures [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures).

EDIT :

to make bidirectionnal working, adapt Award setter :

```
public function setMovie(\Filmboot\MovieBundle\Document\Movie $movie)   {
    $movie->setAward($this);
    return $this->movie = $movie;
}
```

and adapt persistance with cascade persist :

```
/**
 * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Movie", mappedBy="awards", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $movie;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've done what you say me but I have the following error: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Notice: Undefined offset: movie-1 in ../vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/ReferenceRepository.php line 145
I also have one question. If the relationship between Award and Movie is bidirectional, which one has to go first in Order?

Comment: You have this error because you never add the reference $this->addReference('movie-1', $movie); or perhaps movies are loaded after awards (have you check order, low order is loaded before high order) ? In my sample i implicitly used an iterator $i ($this->addReference('movie-'.$i, $movie);) but you need to adapt ;) No special priority between Awards and Movie, don't forget to add adapt the setter of Award (see the edit in my answer)

Comment: Finally I have solved my error, but I don't understand when you say "No special priority when Awards and Movie". So I have made a new question. Link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953315/bidirectional-references-on-doctrine-fixtures

Comment: Can you set my post as solving question as my answer solved your initial problem, and the other problem is another stack question ?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message you got is clear enough. Here's the way you may fix this bad arguments mapping issue.

Instead of setting an integer as a `movie` to the `awards` array you're using to populate the `document` instance. Why don't you just set a given `Movie` entity you already persisted.

To do that, you'll have to load one or many `movies` (it depends on your needs) and set this/those entit(y/ies) as argument(s) to populate your `document` instances.

**An example,** 
Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264758/how-can-i-get-an-entity-from-doctrine-fixture-reference) (on the question) of user(s) populated by already persisted userGroup(s). You might use here the same idea.